# Zsh "(eval):61: = not found" error after Anaconda update

Tags: python, anaconda, zsh

I recently updated Anaconda (`conda update --all`) and I now see the following message in my zsh command line on opening:

`(eval):61: = not found`

Things still seem to work fine, I can call `conda`, etc., but the error seems strange. I'm sure it's some small thing that I missed on the update, or updating in my .zshrc file (I'm using oh-my-zsh).

Comment: I see the same thing. This is probably a bug in the initialization function that conda runs (he says without any supporting evidence)

Comment: See: https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/8476

Comment: Ah! Resolved! Thanks for the link.

Comment: @darthbith I replace "==" with "=" at Conda.sh, but still has the error. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the tip from @darthbith, I managed to sort this out. The trick is indeed replacing `==` with `=` in the `conda.sh` shell script.

The trick is to find the right one as there are multiple. For me, what worked was making that change in this one: 
`‎⁨~/anaconda3⁩/lib⁩/python3.6⁩/site-packages⁩/conda⁩/shell⁩/etc⁩/profile.d⁩/conda.sh`

Near the bottom of this script, replace the `==` with `=` in these two `if` conditions:

```
 if [ "${_CE_CONDA+x}" == "condax" ]; then

 if [ "${PATH+x}" == "x" ]; then
```